# Name of scientists that study sapient life

Tags: science-fiction, fantasy-races, language

In a fantasy world I'm creating, one of the characters biologist who studies the other intelligent beings.  Originally, I was going to name them a Xeno biologist.  But that would implies that other beings would be from and evolved from another world, which didn't.

**What is the correct term for such a researcher?**

Comment: It's not really a world building question.  Anyway, you would need to specify the category of intelligent life. Anthropologists study creatures that are basically human-like, from the Greek "anthropos" meaning human. You would need a root word for the group of creatures they study. For example, elf is xotikó in Greek. Or gígas is orc.

Comment: I think you need to specify what *aspect* of these other sophonts is being studied. Someone focused on their biology probably *would* be a xenobiologist. Culture? Xenoanthropologist. Psychology? Xenopsychologist. Economy? Xenoeconomist. And so on. Basically, take the name of whatever you'd call the scientist if they were studying humans and add "xeno-" to the front. So your real question might be "what do we call someone who studies sapience?". (Which you should go ask on English.SE, not here.)

Comment: Clarification: are you asking for a general English term for someone who studies sophont biology, culture, and the like; or are you looking for an English word that would serve to translate an ***in-world terminology***?

Answer (score 7):

Xenoanthropology. Or possibly some variant of it, depending on just what aspects were being studied.

Xeno- is often taken to mean "from another planet" in most of these words, but it originally meant something like "foreign". It would apply on worlds where two unrelated sapient species co-evolved.

Comment: Xeno pretty much means Alien, the issue is that our definition of Alien has shifted as it used to mainly mean "foreign or unknown", hence the term "illegal aliens". However, in this case xenobiologist would be appropriate for "another planet" because they would have to study life that could function on entirely different principles from life on Earth. I would imagine if we ever discover alien life and need to separate branches of biology, we would then have something like terrabiologist.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle I don't think xenobiologist works... that implies studying all the life of that other planet (or, competely separate origin of life on the same planet that is unrelated to the character's own). If they are studying sapients, then I take it to mean that they are studying their culture, sociology, psychology, and so on... and I'd put the xeno-prefix on anthropology. But yes, we agree that xeno- prefix belongs on whatever the base term is that he needs.

Comment: `Xeno-...originally meant something like "foreign"` Ummm... and ánthrōpos (ἄνθρωπος, "human")  - so, "study of the foreign humans"???

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi Yes. Something like that. English does have several constructions for "non-humans who are intelligent or have civilization", using one of several roots. But none of those make sense for the science itself. Anthropology might generally mean the study of humans, but more narrowly it is the study of things that make humans different from all other animals, and if another species displayed those characteristics we'd learn about them by doing comparative anthropology. Just need to tack xeno- on the front.

Answer (score 3):

**Sapientologist.**

from OED

> sapient, adj. and n
>
> Etymology:  < Old French sapient or < Latin sapient-em wise, noun,
>   wise man, present participle of sapĕre to have a taste or savour, to
>   be sensible or wise.

The scholar who studies intelligence would not be limited to a given race, species, provenance, or even living vs nonliving things.  One could be a sapientologist in our own world and study crows, dogs, humans and dolphins just as a linguist would study the commonalities and difference between languages and forms of communication.

Your sapientologist studies the humanoid species, nonhumanoid intelligences alien and otherwise, as well as magical intelligence, spirits, elementals or anything else which can be said to think.  The study is not so much the entity, but how the process of thought works and differs from platform to platform.

Plus you named this discipline in the title of your question, Seraphim!

Comment: I might push that further into the Greek. Sapientology just sounds too much like Scientology. "Wise" in Ancient Greek could be either "Sophoi" or "Phronesis". The former is probably more related to sapient, but the latter is more of a specific type of wisdom sometimes called "practical virtue" that is discussed in philosophy quite a bit, which I think is more related conceptually. Sophology, or Phronology (Phronesiology?) both seem like better terms to me.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle:   Sophology is good.  As re the latter I want to wave the flag for more Phrenology, a science which has fallen into a sad decline over recent decades.

Comment: @TitaniumTurtle - wouldn't it mean "the study of wisdom" rather than the "study of sapient beings"?

Comment: Xeno-[ethology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethology) - study of animal behaviour, usually with a focus on behaviour under natural conditions, and viewing behaviour as an evolutionarily adaptive trait. (will require shifting the meaning of "animal" into "non-human")

Comment: FWIW, "sophoi" gives us "[sophont](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophont)", which is the blanket term (i.e. includes both humans and eligible extraterrestrials) for beings possessed of sapience. (Not to be confused with beings possessed of *sentience*, which is a much lower bar.) I don't know if anyone has tried to coin "sophontology", though, or whether that would even be an improvement over "sophology". (Now, would that be sophology, or *xeno*sophology?)

Answer (score 2):

**Some derivative of Anthropology**

Along the lines of the suggestion made by @puppetsock in the comments, Anthropology is the study of humans coming from Ancient Greek "Anthropos". Following the same pattern for whatever specific race you are studying would simply make sense.

In a fantasy setting:

- Aelfology might be for Elves (Old-English root because the Romans and Ancient Greeks didn't have the same concept of "Elf" like we imagine, and Mideival Greeks "Xitiko" literally means "outlandish thing")
- Horkology for Orcs (Orc comes from Latin Orcus, underworld god of broken oaths, which came from Ancient Greek Horkos)
- Pygmology for Dwarves
- Drakonology for Dragons

That is a pretty simple list to build off of.

For a SciFi setting you may want to adopt something based on the name or origin of the alien species:

- Aerology for Martians (Aero from Ares which of course became Mars in Latin)
- Kentaurology for Alpha Centauri or Proxima Centauri (Kentauros is greek for Centaur)
- Ahrakology for Vulcans (unfortunately Vulcanology is already taken by volcano scientists, but according to a Star Trek dictionary I found online their home planet is Ah'rak)

Basically just take the name of the species or their origin (possibly use a roman-greko equivalent) and add the -ology suffix. BOOM!